# Derivation of fractional Brownian motion covariance

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In all articles about fBm this formula of variance is given as the definition:

$$ Cov\big[B_H(t),B_H(s)\big] = \frac{1}{2}\big(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}\big).$$

However, nowhere I could find the derivation of it from the original fBm formula:

$$B_H(t) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(H+1/2)}\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)^{H-1/2}dB(s).$$

Could you help me to derive it or give a link where it can be found?

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with Ito isometry? Allows you to turn $\mathbb E[B_H(t)B_H(s)] = \mathrm{Cov}(B_H(t), B_H(s))$ into some integrals over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The process $B_H$ as defined in your question is **not** a standard fractional Brownian motion; for instance it is lacking stationarity of the increments. See the discussion in [this paper](ftp://optics.sinp.msu.ru/users/Anna/stat0/fr/other/59841897fr.pdf), (bottom of) page 2

Answer (score 1):

The fBm with the Hurst parameter $H\in (0,1)$, $B_{t}^{H}$ for $t\in \mathbb{%
R}$, is a zero mean Gaussian process with covariance
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}(B_{t}^{H}B_{s}^{H})=R_{H}(s,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(
|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}\right) \,.  \label{cov}
\end{equation*}

For $t>0$, it has the following integral representation:
\begin{equation*}
B_{t}^{H}=\frac{1}{c_{H}}\left\{ \int_{-\infty }^{0}\left[
(t-u)^{H-1/2}-(-u)^{H-1/2}\right] dW_{u}+\int_{0}^{t}(t-u)^{H-1/2}dW_{u}%
\right\} ,  \label{mand}
\end{equation*}
where $W_{t}$ is a standard Brownian motion, and $c_{H}=\Gamma(H+1/2)$.

For details, please see [Robinso](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375898002456) or [Davidson](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308005458).